# Updating a database using post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a calendar where the background color of the day cells can be changed by the administrator. The change gets saved to the server. Right now, it's not working. Here's a portion of the JavaScript:

```
for(i=0; i<myDays.length; i++) { // Goes through each TD and creates a click event
myDays[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.classList.contains("avail")) {
        this.classList.toggle("avail");
        this.classList.toggle("halfy");
        $.post("classChange.php", { dID: this.id, dClass: "halfy" } );
    }
```

This is the PHP code in classChange.php:

```
    if(isset($_POST["dID"]) ){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE original SET class=? WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $dClass, $dID);

    $dID = $_POST["dID"];
    $dClass = $_POST["dClass"];

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "Code error, dummy!";
}
```

Clicking on a cell correctly changes the class (and color) of the cell, but does not update the database. I'm not getting any errors. I think it must be a problem with the post() code, or the PHP code. Any advice?

Comment: defining your variables after you use them isn't going to be a successful practice.  If Catalin Minovici has sufficiently solved your problem, please award him the green tick, otherwise please edit your quesiton to clarify what issues remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the variables first before using them.

```
$dID = $_POST["dID"];
$dClass = $_POST["dClass"];
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE original SET class=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $dClass, $dID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your method, and it did not work. I am using  $db in place of the usual $conn for various reasons. I am using MySQLi, not PDO. "ss" just indicates that the next two variables are strings. I've used this method before; it can be found on W3School: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

I've been getting PHP errors for other code that I did, but how can I check? I added a console.log to the JS code, and the correct info is being generated on a click. Please help if you can!

Comment: Defining variables before using them was definitely a change to be made in your code. Add `printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);` after execute(). Do you have any mysql error ?

Comment: I made the recommended changes, and also added this to the PHP: 
`echo json_encode(array("resID"=>$dID, "resClass"=>$dClass));`. 

I then added "output" to the JS code: 
`$.post("classChange.php", { dID: this.id, dClass: "halfy" }, function(data) { console.log(data.resID); console.log(data.resClass); }, "json" );`. 

Now my code works. Not sure which bit solved the problem, but thanks!